# What's the adjective from 'emit'?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, suffixes

I'd like to know what's the right adjective from the word 'to emit'. 
Is is emitting or emitted radiation?  Or are they  both used interchangeably?

Comment: How do you want to use this adjective? Do you want to describe the object that is emitting light, or the light that is emitted?

Comment: It depends on how it's used. "Radiation-emitting material is to be handled according to strict regulations." vs "The emitted radiation irradiates the shield."

Comment: Both are legitimate adjectives, although they're not completely interchangeable. *emitting* is the present participle, and *emitted* is the past participle. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Present_participle.

Answer (score 13):

I'd have to partly disagree with DavePhD.

There are at least three adjectival forms of the verb "emit". Emissive is used to the abstract concept of emission, as in the "emissive power" example given; however "radiation" in the OP's question would normally be described as "emitted", particularly in the concrete sense of describing a past event, so:

> The laser was activated and the emitted radiation measured.

would be more natural than

> The laser was activated and the emissive radiation measured.

Lastly, the example mentioned in comments still stands: an LED is a "light-emitting diode", so "x-emitting" is sometimes the correct adjective to use!

Comment: I'd agree that in particular reference to the radiation itself, that "emitted" sounds more natural. The term "emissive" might be more general as describing the production and overall measurement details. I would caution that both uses of those terms seems redundant, since there is no such thing as un-emitted radiation. Radiation is by definition both "emitted" and "emissive".

Comment: Indeed - a fair point. I suppose it can be useful sometimes to distinguish the emitted radiation (emitted just now from an experiment) from the background radiation (still emitted, but not in the studied interaction)

Comment: And I would now that that this perspective supports the use of `emitted` in the sense that one would talk about some fraction being "emitted from" one source and another fraction "emitted from" another.

Answer (score 4):

emissive:

> having the power to radiate something, especially light, heat, or radiation

For example, from  [A Textbook on Heat Transfer, page 109](https://books.google.com/books?id=-VgAZm6KWrwC&pg=PA109&dq=%22emissive%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_y_Xo2sDMAhWIPj4KHV8IB7QQ6AEIQDAI#v=onepage&q=%22emissive%22&f=false):

> The total hemispherical emissivity of a surface is the ratio of the total hemispherical **emissive** power of the surface to the total hemispherical **emissive** power of a black surface at the same temperature

The book uses the word "emissive" 11 times just on this one page!

Other examples:

[A Metal Selective Microwave **Emissive** Detector for Gas Chromatography](http://chromsci.oxfordjournals.org/content/12/10/585.short)

[The Visibitlity of the 10-CM Radio-**Emissive** Region and its Application in Finding the 10-CM Quiet Sun.](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1960ApJ...132..435C)

[Broad Spectral Domain Fluorescence Wavelength Modulation of Visible and Near-Infrared **Emissive** Polymersomes](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja055571b)

[Investigation of ionic composition during expansion of laser-produced plasma by means of x-ray **emissive** spectroscopy and mass-spectroscopy methods](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-8949/52/2/011/meta)

[Plasma Potential Measurements by Electron **Emissive** Probes](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/rsi/37/4/10.1063/1.1720213)

[Strongly **emissive** individual DNA-encapsulated Ag nanoclusters as single-molecule fluorophores](http://www.pnas.org/content/104/31/12616.short)

[Stable Lanthanide Luminescence Agents Highly **Emissive** in Aqueous Solution:  Multidentate 2-Hydroxyisophthalamide Complexes of Sm3+, Eu3+, Tb3+, Dy3+](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja0379363)

Comment: DavePHD: Oops, yes, all I saw at first was 'emissivity'. Never mind. (deleting comments).